# How to recognise tailwindcss functions and directives in sveltekit?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using [`SvelteKit`](https://kit.svelte.dev/) and [`Tailwind CSS`](https://tailwindcss.com/) and VSCode.

When I use tailwind directives and functions into a `<style>`, I get lint errors:

For example for `@screen`:

[image]

```
Unknown at rule @screencss(unknownAtRules)
```

But it does work (meaning it behaves as per the tailwind doc.

I also tried `@media screen(lg)`, but I also get lint errors:

```
Identifier or parenthesis is expected

If you expect this syntax to work, here are some suggestions: 
If you use less/SCSS with `svelte-preprocess`, did you add `lang="scss"`/`lang="less"` to your `style` tag? If you use SCSS, it may be necessary to add the path to your NODE runtime to the setting `svelte.language-server.runtime`, or use `sass` instead of `node-sass`. 
Did you setup a `svelte.config.js`? 
See https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/tree/master/docs#using-with-preprocessors for more info.svelte(css-syntax-error)
{ expectedcss(css-lcurlyexpected)
at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)
```

[image]

---

I tried following [these steps](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5258#discussioncomment-1979394) but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think for `directive` related config:

in `postcss..config.js`

```
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

and in `app.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

make sure in top level `+layout.svelte`

```
import '../app.css';
```